# FireBase - Add user to user list

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

Hi I am trying to learn firebase now that Parse will be shutting down and I am having some trouble with adding users to my database.

Following the iOS tutorials on the site, I first listen for user list using:

```
- (void)setUpRootReference {
self.rootReference = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"firebaseurl"];
// Attach a block to read the data at our posts reference
[self.rootReference observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@", snapshot.value);
    if (snapshot.value != [NSNull null]) {
        userDic = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"users"];
        NSLog(@"user dictionary: %@", userDic);
    }
} withCancelBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}];
}
```

then after the user has succesfully logged in using Instagram I want to append the new user to my existing user list. But right now it is just being over written and Im always left with one user.

Here is my completion code after user sign up:

```
//create a path on firebase for users
        Firebase *usersRef = [self.rootReference childByAppendingPath: @"users"];

        [userDic setValue:newUserDic forKey:newUser.instagramHandle];
        [usersRef setValue:userDic];
```

Does anyone know how I can just append a value to the existing dictionary of users versus erasing it and creating a new one every time?

thanks

UPDATE:

I figured out how to make it work. Everytime you create a new user you want to make a new reference to that user

solution:

```
//create a path on firebase for users
        Firebase *allUsersRef = [self.rootReference childByAppendingPath: @"users"];
        Firebase *newUserRef = [allUsersRef childByAppendingPath:newUser.instagramHandle];
        [newUserRef setValue:newUserDic];
```

Now there will be a new user dictionary added and the key is the users instagram handle

Comment: Idk about firebase but to modify an existing dictionary, you have to use `NSMutableDictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: This is covered in the [documentation on storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing), which indeed uses `childByAppendingPath`. The entire iOS guide is well worth a read.

Comment: See also this closely related question from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678559/new-user-vs-old-firebase-facebook-authentication

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *nickname = @{
    @"nickname": @"Igor Kuznetsov",
};
[userRef updateChildValues: nickname];
```

There is a method called updateChildValues. Try something like this.
[userRef updateChildValues: nickname];
My example above will change for instance nickname of user, in your case you can change nickname for attribute in which you have interest.